# webmaster`SELECT * FROM `st_sponsors` WHERE 1 LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Sorry, I am completely ignorant about MYSQL and don't understand what I have to do.
Thank you for your help

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`webmaster`SELECT * FROM `st_sponsors` WHERE 1 LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

`1 webmasterSELECT * FROM st_sponsors WHERE 1`

! This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.

```
$sql = "SELECT `st_sponsors`.`webmaster`\n"
    . "FROM st_sponsors\n"
    . "ORDER BY `st_sponsors`.`webmaster` ASC\n"
    . " LIMIT 0, 30 ";
```

Comment: What is `\n` your query? Remove it. And why you have used `webmaster` before `select`?

Comment: mysql or SQL-Server?

Comment: And get rid of those `."` things too

Comment: Please clean you SQL don't use concat if if not to complicated

Comment: The sql in the error message seems completely unrelated to the sql you are showing...

Answer (score 2):

You have to add spaces between clauses (and you don't need `\n`):

```
$sql = "SELECT `st_sponsors`.`webmaster` "
     . "FROM `st_sponsors` "
     . "ORDER BY `st_sponsors`.`webmaster` ASC "
     . "LIMIT 0, 30";
```

Or just:

```
$sql = "SELECT s.`webmaster` FROM `st_sponsors` s ORDER BY s.`webmaster` LIMIT 0, 30";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$sql = "SELECT sp.webmaster FROM st_sponsors sp
ORDER BY sp.webmaster ASC LIMIT 0, 30";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

`$sql = "SELECT s.webmaster FROM st_spomsors s ORDER BY s.webmaster ASC WHERE 1 LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0";`

Comment: Could you provide more information than "you can use this"?